# Enum constructor calls ara only allowed inside the enum class

Tags: grails, groovy, enums

I'm working on a grails project. Right now I have a very disturbing problem. I have an enum called Status like this:

```
enum Status {

    ENABLED("Habilitado"), DISABLED ("Desabilitado")

    String type

    private Status(String type) {
        this.type = type
    }

    def String toString() {
        return this.type
    }

    static list() {
        [ENABLED, DISABLED]
    }
}
```

I also have a controller called TesterController, which is where I keep getting errors saying "Enum constructor calls are only allowed inside the enum class" The thing is: I do not call the enum constructor from inside the controller class! Here it is:

```
class TesterController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

    def index() {
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }

    def list() {
        def minElems = 10

        if(params.max) minElems = params.int('max')

        params.max = Math.min(minElems, 100)

        [testers: Tester.list(params), testerTotal: Tester.count()]
    }

    def create() {
        [tester: new Tester(params)]
    }

    def save() {
        def tester = new Tester(params)
        if (!tester.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [tester: tester])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'ateweb.created.message', args: [tester.name])
        redirect(action: "show", id: tester.id)
    }

    def show() {
        def tester = Tester.get(params.id)
        if (!tester) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'ateweb.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'tester.label', default: 'Tester'), params.name])
            redirect(action: "list")
            return
        }

        [tester: tester]
    }

    def edit() {
        def tester = Tester.get(params.id)
        if (!tester) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'ateweb.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'tester.label', default: 'Tester'), params.name])
            redirect(action: "list")
            return
        }

        [tester: tester]
    }

    def update() {
        def tester = Tester.get(params.id)
        if (!tester) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'ateweb.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'tester.label', default: 'Tester'), params.name])
            redirect(action: "list")
            return
        }

        if (params.version) {
            def version = params.version.toLong()
            if (tester.version > version) {
                tester.errors.rejectValue("version", "ateweb.optimistic.locking.failure",
                      [message(code: 'tester.label', default: 'Tester')] as Object[],
                      "Another user has updated this Tester while you were editing")
                render(view: "edit", model: [tester: tester])
                return
            }
        }

        tester.properties = params

        if (!tester.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "edit", model: [tester: tester])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'ateweb.updated.message', args: [tester.name])
        redirect(action: "show", id: tester.id)
    }
}
```

Ok. So I am lost with this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Posting the actual error that is printed out would be better than an anecdote about an error

Comment: What IDE are you using? I've seen Netbeans through some weird errors about Enums.

Comment: SpringSource Tool Suite. It does have some weird errors. Although my program runs normally. I feel guilty though.

Comment: Haha, well my advice is that if it's not stopping you running your app then just curse STS under your breath and keep on. :) That's what I do with Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the definition of your `Status` class, though I don't know if these are the cause of your problem

```
enum Status {

    ENABLED("Habilitado"), DISABLED ("Desabilitado")

    String type

    // delcaring the constructor private doesn't make much sense because
    // enum constuctors can never be called outside the class
    private Status(String type) {
        this.type = type
    }

    // return type is declared as both def (Object) and String
    def String toString() {
        return this.type
    }

    // this is identical to the automatically-generated values() method
    static list() {
        [ENABLED, DISABLED]
    }
}
```

Redefine this class as

```
enum Status {

    ENABLED("Habilitado"), DISABLED ("Desabilitado")

    String type

    Status(String type) {
        this.type = type
    }

    String toString() {
        return this.type
    }
}
```

and use `values()` instead of the deleted `list()` method, and maybe your problem will disappear

Comment: No, it didn't work. Thanks for the tip though (+1). It's funny because TesterController (the class where the compiler say the error is) does not use enums per se. It uses the Tester class, that uses the Status enum. Quite a mistery to me right now.